# Using results from form to do mysql request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms

I'm a total noob in JS, but I'm trying to improve and do a SQL request through nodeJS. I've installer mysql thanks to NPM and searched the web on how to do it.
I'm pretty sure I'm close to what I need to do, but I don't manage to have the expected result.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>Envoi formulaire</title>
    </head>
      <body>
      <h1> Vous êtes dans l'endroit pour ajouter des objets </h1>

      <p> What do u wanna do ? </p>

      <form name="monform" id="formulaire_ajout">
        <input type="text" name="objet" id="nom_objet" placeholder="Le nom de votre objet" size="50" autofocus />
        <input type="text" name="poids" id="poids_objet" placeholder="Le poids de votre objet" size="50" autofocus />
        <input type="submit" id="Bouton_valid" value="ok" />
      </form>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        Bouton_valid.addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert(document.monform.objet.value + document.monform.poids.value);

        var nomobjet=document.monform.objet.value;
        var mysql = require('mysql');

          var con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "user",
            password: "mypasswd",
            database: "mydbname"
          });

          con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var sql = "INSERT INTO Objet (Nom_complet, Marque, texte_Preparation, texte_Rechercher, texte_Configuration, nom_Usage, Type, Icone_Statut) VALUES('Test2','"+document.monform.poids_objet.value+"', 'Test' , 'Test2', 'Tes3' ,'Nom easy', '5255', '12' )";

            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log("1 record inserted");
            });
          });

      });

        </script>

      </body>
  </html>
```

So I only want to add an item in Objet in my database and one of the attributes of the object is passed through a form. But when I use this code nothing happens.

Can someone give me a piece of advice ? Thanks in advance

Comment: NodeJs code should be on server. It seems that you are trying to use it on client side, which eventually will not work for you.

Comment: Damn it's seems you're right, I didn't fully understand how it works but after searching now I do, thanks for your answer